# fraction of ounces increasing each time?

Tags: java, math

```
public static String convertGramsToPoundsAndOunces(String grams) {
    double weightInKG = Double.parseDouble(grams) / 1000;
    double pounds = weightInKG / 0.45359237;
    double lbs = Math.floor(pounds);
    double fraction = (pounds - lbs) * 16;
    return String.valueOf(Math.round(lbs) + "lbs" + " " + String.format("%.1f", new BigDecimal(fraction)) + "oz");
}
```

From the service i am getting `305lb 0.050469oz`, but when its getting converted its displaying `305lbs 0.1oz`, but it should show just 305lbs.

Comment: Welcome to IEEE 754, enjoy your stay.

Comment: Two comments: 1) What's the point of `new BigDecimal(fraction))`? You can't add precision to something that is imprecise by doing this AFTER all the calculations have already taken place. 2) `0.050469` rounds up to `0.1` in a `%.1f` context. Why is this surprising? If you want different rounding behaviour, you need to write code for it.

Comment: @Patashu make that an answer...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: This is not an IEEE 754 issue. Even if every operation shown in the code rounded up, IEEE 754 arithmetic would not change a mass of 138347.1 grams (which is more than 305 pounds, .05 ounces) to 305 pounds and .050469 ounces. Therefore, the error is in the input string or the OP’s expectations, not the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

`String.format()` rounding not as OP expected, but correct.

`String.format("%.1f", ...` properly converts `0.050469` to `"0.1"`.  The format directs a rounding to the nearest 0.1 and 0.050469 is closer to 0.1 than any other tenth.

---

Should the OP want a different rounding mode, it may be more consistent to covert grams directly to ounces `oz = gr*(1/1000.0/0.45359237*16.0)`, round as desired and then split into pounds & ounces.  Further, this would help with negative `grams`, which are not converted correctly.

The `Math.round(lbs)` likely not needed as it follows `lbs = Math.floor(pounds)`.

Notes:
0.45359237 is the correct *exact* conversion factor.
`grams` input was something like "138347.10362".